# Neo4j: Unknown command :use

Tags: neo4j

I'm following this doc: https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases

> If we want to see the system information (view, create/delete, manage databases), we will need to switch to the `system` database.
> We can do that with the `:use` command then telling it which database we want.
>
> Command: `:use system`
>
> Results:
> [image]

But when I try it locally it says:

> `UnknownCommandError: Unknown command :use system`

> [image: my screenshot]

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the manual you have quoted:

> **Prerequisites**
> Please have Neo4j (version 4.0 or later) downloaded and
> installed. It helps to have read the section on graph databases.

> In Neo4j (v4.0+), we can create and use more than one active database
> at the same time

And you seem to be using v3.5.1. Hence the issue.
Please upgrade to v4.0+ to be able to manage multiple databases.

In Neo4j 3.5.x or below, you can use change the neo4j.conf config property [dbms.active_database](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.active_database) to change which database the dbms will use, this may be easier for you than replacing file contents.